# Kubernetes Jobs: How to manually end a job without killing current running pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I have a job which currently runs with "pararellism" spec set to 5. (5 running pods at each given moment) I want the job to stop spawning new pods after each fail, but let the current running pods end uninterrupted.

Tried to set pararellism to 1 in yaml and apply the changes, but it instantly moves the pod to termination phase.

Sadly I cannot upload the yml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [--cascade=orphan](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/use-cascading-deletion/#set-orphan-deletion-policy) flag to `orphan` these dependents using `kubectl`

```
kubectl delete jobs --cascade=orphan
```

Comment: Sounds promising, I will give it a shot tomorrow, but should I be worried about any resources hanging? Im not too familiar with k8s.